# If I have a VOB file, what do I need to name it as and what other files do I need, to make a playable DVD of it?

Tags: dvd-burning

If I have a VOB file, what do I need to name it, and what other files do I need, to make a playable DVD of it?

I have tried a program called DVD Styler and given it an MP4 and gotten it to write to a directory on a hard drive, and used imgburn to write that to a DVD, and that played. But I find DVD Styler takes a long time. Maybe even 2 hours for a 2 hour video. (eg here is the ffmpeg log it shows. 2Mb/s = 0.25MB/s , and on a 1.4GB 2h 30min file, is  1400/0.25 =5600 seconds = 93 minutes = 1hr 30min   That's almost as long as the video.

```
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-12-27T03:00:21.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 ac3
frame=24511 fps=157 q=4.4 size=  253440kB time=00:16:20.46 bitrate=2117.5kbits/s dup=1000 drop=13 speed=6.26x    
More than 1000 frames duplicated
frame=141639 fps=164 q=3.7 size= 1554898kB time=01:34:25.77 bitrate=2248.2kbits/s dup=5797 drop=13 speed=6.57x
```

The vob file didn't take that long to generate though as far as I recall at least.

I'm wondering if a program like DVD Styler is really necessary if I have the vob file.  And supposing I just want one MP4 on a DVD.  And I converted it to a VOB file e.g. via   `ffmpeg -i bia.mp4 -target ntsc-dvd -preset ultrafast bia.vob` as mentioned https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-January/012989.html

I want the simplest most minimalistic DVD.. Is there anything simple I can do manually to create that?

Comment: Reprocessing video files usually takes a long time on an average computer not designed or optimized for video processing.

Comment: The dvd has to be "authored" so it can play, there are a few other files created while software authors the dvd and they wont play without them. Just browse any movie dvd and see all the files other than .vob.